# Unable to get Fuzzy C means working

Tags: java, c#, cluster-analysis, data-mining

I need to find out why the centroid positions so close to each other?

I found some fuzzy c means code here http://msugvnua000.web710.discountasp.net/Posts/Details/3347 and tried very hard to convert it to java code (below) but there is something I am missing.

I also tried looking at this implementation http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91675/Computer-Vision-Applications-with-C-Fuzzy-C-means the code looks similar but it's different because instead of updating the cluster indexes the membership values get updates - I'm not sure why this change was implemented?

```
public class CMeansAlgorithm3 {
    private static int fuzzyness = 2;

    private final Map<Double, Species> integerClusterHashMap = new HashMap<Double, Species>();

    /// Array containing all points used by the algorithm
    private List<Job> points;

    /// Gets or sets membership matrix
    public double[][] U;

    /// Algorithm precision
    private double eps = Math.pow(10, -5);

    /// Gets or sets objective function
    private double J;

    /// Gets or sets log message
    public String log;

    private List<Species> clusterList;

    public CMeansAlgorithm3(List<Job> points, int clusterSize){
        this.points = points;
        clusterList = initialiseCentroids(points, clusterSize);
        U = new double[points.size()][clusterList.size()];
        calculateClusterMembershipValues();
        recalculateClusterIndexes();
    }

    private void calculateClusterMembershipValues() {
        // Iterate through all points to create initial U matrix
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            Job p = points.get(i);
            double sum = 0.0;

            for (int j = 0; j < clusterList.size(); j++) {
                Cluster c = clusterList.get(j);
                double diff = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p.getMidpointX() - c.getCentroid().getX(), 2.0) + Math.pow(p.getMidpointY() - c.getCentroid().getY(), 2.0));
                U[i][j] = (diff == 0) ? eps : diff;
                sum += U[i][j];
             }

             double sum2 = 0.0;
             for (int j = 0; j < clusterList.size(); j++) {
                 U[i][j] = 1.0 / Math.pow(U[i][j] / sum, 2.0 / (fuzzyness - 1.0));
                sum2 += U[i][j];
             }

             for (int j = 0; j < clusterList.size(); j++) {
                U[i][j] = U[i][j] / sum2;
             }    
        }
   }

   /// Recalculates cluster indexes
   private void recalculateClusterIndexes() {
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            double max = -1.0;
            Job p = points.get(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < clusterList.size(); j++) {
                max = U[i][j] > max ? U[i][j] : max;
//              if (max < U[i][j]) {
//                    max = U[i][j];
//                    p.setClusterIndex((max == 0.5) ? 0.5 : j);
//              }
            }
            p.setClusterIndex(max);
        }
    }

    /// Perform a complete run of the algorithm until the desired accuracy is achieved.
    /// For demonstration issues, the maximum Iteration counter is set to 20.
    /// Algorithm accuracy
    /// The number of steps the algorithm needed to complete
    public List<Species> run(double accuracy) {
        int k = 0;
        int maxIterations = 100;

        do {
            k++;
            J = calculateObjectiveFunction();
            calculateClusterCentroids();
            step();
            double Jnew = calculateObjectiveFunction();

            if (Math.abs(J - Jnew) < accuracy) break;
        }
        while (maxIterations > k);

        assignJobsToClusters();
        return clusterList;
    }

    /// Calculate the objective function
    /// The objective function as double value
    private double calculateObjectiveFunction() {
        double Jk = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < this.points.size();i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < clusterList.size(); j++) {
                Jk += Math.pow(U[i][j], this.fuzzyness) * Math.pow(this.calculateEuclidDistance(points.get(i), clusterList.get(j)), 2);
            }
        }
        return Jk;
    }

    private List<Species> initialiseCentroids(final List<Job> dataSet, final int speciesSize) {
        final List<Species> clusterList = new ArrayList<Species>();
        final List<Integer> uniqueIndexes = ToolBox.uniqueIndexes(dataSet.size(), speciesSize);

        for (int i=0; i< uniqueIndexes.size(); i++){
            final int randomIndex = uniqueIndexes.get(i);
            final Species species = new Species(i);
            final Centroid centroid = new Centroid(dataSet.get(randomIndex).getMidpointX(), dataSet.get(randomIndex).getMidpointY(), i);
            species.setCentroid(centroid);
            speciesList.add(species);
        }
        return clusterList;
    }

    /// Perform one step of the algorithm
    public void step() {
        for (int c = 0; c < clusterList.size(); c++) {
            for (int h = 0; h < points.size(); h++) {
                double top;
                top = calculateEuclidDistance(points.get(h), clusterList.get(c));
                if (top < 1.0) top = eps;

                // sumTerms is the sum of distances from this data point to all clusters.
                double sumTerms = 0.0;

                for (int ck = 0; ck < clusterList.size(); ck++) {
                    double thisDistance = calculateEuclidDistance(points.get(h), clusterList.get(ck));
                    if (thisDistance < 1.0) thisDistance = eps;
                    sumTerms += Math.pow(top / thisDistance, 2.0 / (fuzzyness - 1.0));

                }
                // Then the membership value can be calculated as...
                U[h][c] = (1.0 / sumTerms);
            }
        }

        recalculateClusterIndexes();
    }

    /// Calculates Euclid distance between point and centroid
    /// Point
    /// Centroid
    /// Calculated distance
    private double calculateEuclidDistance(Job p, Species c) {
        return ToolBox.calculateDistance(p.getMidpointX(), p.getMidpointY(), c.getCentroid().getX(), c.getCentroid().getY());
    }

    /// Calculates the centroids of the clusters
    private void calculateClusterCentroids() {
        for (int j = 0; j < clusterList.size(); j++) {
            Species c = clusterList.get(j);
            double uX = 0.0;
            double uY = 0.0;
            double membershipSum = 0.0;

            for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
                Job p = points.get(i);

                double uu = Math.pow(U[i][j], this.fuzzyness);
                uX += uu * p.getMidpointX();
                uY += uu * p.getMidpointY();
                membershipSum += uu;
            }

            c.setMembershipSum(membershipSum);
            c.getCentroid().setX(((uX / membershipSum)));
            c.getCentroid().setY(((uY / membershipSum)));

            log += String.format("Cluster Centroid: (" + c.getCentroid().getX() + "; " + c.getCentroid().getY() + ")");
        }
    }

    private void assignJobsToClusters(){
        for (final Cluster cluster : clusterList){
            if (!integerClusterHashMap.containsKey(cluster.getMembershipSum()))
                integerClusterHashMap.put(cluster.getMembershipSum(), cluster);
        }

        for (Job job : points){
            final double clusterIndex = job.getClusterIndex();
            Species c = integerSpeciesHashMap.get(clusterIndex);

            if (c != null) {
                c.add(job);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why cant I assign the datapoints to clusters? How can I change the code so that it actually clusters the points? The code use to put all the datapoints in one cluster but now it just sets the clusterIndex to 0.5 for all datapoints.

Comment: Could you edit your question to add that comment in it?

Comment: What language is this? The linked pages talk about C#, you tagged C and Java. It's obviously not C. Please clarify and set tags correctly, thanks.

Comment: Why the `c#` tag?

Answer (score 0):

fuzzy c means code in java

```
package f;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Anooj.k.varghese
 */
public class F{

 static Double data_set[][]=new Double[20000][100];
    static Double diff[][]=new Double[20000][100];
        static Double eud[][]=new Double[20000][1000];
    static Double intial_centroid[][]=new Double[300][400];
     static Double new_center[][]=new Double[300][400];
    static int num = 0;
    static int row=4;//rows in Your DataSet here i use iris dataset 

    static int cnum;
    static int itc=0;
    static int checker=1;


     private static void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException
        {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("E:/aa.txt"));//Dataset path
        scanner.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        //scanner.useDelimiter(",");
        int lineNo = 0;
            while (scanner.hasNext())
             {
                parseLine(scanner.next(),lineNo);
                lineNo++;
                System.out.println();
             }
             // System.out.println("total"+num); PRINT THE TOTAL
     scanner.close();
        }
    //read file is copey to the data_set
    public static void parseLine(String line,int lineNo)
      { itc=0;
        Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
        lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");
          for(int col=0;col<row;col++)
              {
                  Double arry=lineScanner.nextDouble();
                  data_set[num][col]=arry;                          ///here read  data set is assign the variable data_set
               }
         num++;

        }
    public static void init()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
        { 
         data_set[i][row]=0.0;
         data_set[i][row+1]=0.0;
        }
    }
    public static void print()
    {
        double re=0;
        double a=0;


       if(itc==0)
       {

             System.out.println("ENTER K");
         Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);      
         cnum=sc.nextInt();   //enter the number of cenroid
       System.out.println("centroid");
         for(int i=0;i<cnum;i++)
         {
            for(int j=0;j<row;j++)
                {

                    intial_centroid[i][j]=data_set[i][j];                  //// CENTROID ARE STORED IN AN intial_centroid variable
                    System.out.print(intial_centroid[i][j]);      
                }
            System.out.println();
         }

       }
       else
       {

            for(int i=0;i<cnum;i++)
         {
            for(int j=0;j<row;j++)
                {
                    intial_centroid[i][j]=new_center[i][j];                  //// CENTROID ARE STORED IN AN intial_centroid variable
                    System.out.print(intial_centroid[i][j]);      
                }
            System.out.println();
         }


       }

          for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
        {
                for(int j=0;j<cnum;j++)       
                {
                    re=0;
                     for(int k=0;k<row;k++)
                     {
                            a= (intial_centroid[j][k]-data_set[i][k]);
                            //System.out.println(a);
                             a=a*a;
                             re=re+a;                                                 // store the row sum

                        }

                         diff[i][j]= Math.sqrt(re);// find the squre root
                         System.out.println(diff[i][j]);

        }
        }

    }
    public static void s()
    {

        double b,c;
        for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<cnum;j++)
            {
                c=0.0;
                b=0.0;
                for(int k=0;k<cnum;k++)
                {
                    if(diff[i][k]==0)
                   {
                        b=0;
                    }
                 if(diff[i][k]!=0)
                   {
                    b=diff[i][j]/diff[i][k];
                    }
                    c=c+b;
                }
                if(c==0)
                {
                    eud[i][j]=0.0;
                }
                else
                {
                     eud[i][j]=1/c;
                }
            }


        }
        double a=0;
          for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
        {
            a=0;
            for(int j=0;j<cnum;j++)
            {
                a=a+eud[i][j];
             System.out.print(eud[i][j]+"    ");
            }
            System.out.print("total  "+a);
            System.out.println();
            }
          double aaa;
          int counter=0;
               for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
        {counter=0;
            aaa=eud[i][0];
            for(int j=0;j<cnum;j++)
                        {
                            if(aaa<=eud[i][j])
                            {
                                aaa=eud[i][j];
                                counter=j;
                            }
                        }
          if(itc%2==0)
          {
                data_set[i][row]=(double)counter;
          }

           if(itc%2==1)
          {
               data_set[i][row+1]=(double)counter;
          }
        }
           for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
           {
               for(int j=0;j<=row+1;j++)
               {
                System.out.print(data_set[i][j]+",  ");

               }
               System.out.println();
           }
    }

     public static void newcenter()
          {
              itc++;
              double a=0.0;
              double c=0.0;
              double d=0.0;
              double f=0.0;
              for(int k=0;k<cnum;k++)
              {
                   for(int j=0;j<row;j++)
                  {
                      a=0.0;
                      d=0.0;

                 c=0.0;
                 f=0.0;
                      for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
                      {
                          //System.out.print("edu"+eud[i][k]);
                          a=eud[i][k];
                          a=a*a;
                          c=c+a;
                          //System.out.println("data"+data_set[i][j]);
                          d=a*data_set[i][j];
                          f=f+d;
                      }
                      new_center[k][j]=f/c;
                         System.out.println("centroid new "+new_center[k][j]);
                     // j=row+5;
                    //  k=cnum+5;

                  }
              }
          }


     public static void print11()
    {
        System.out.println();
         System.out.println();
          System.out.println();
        System.out.println("----OUTPUT----");
        int c=0;
        int a=0;
        for(int i=0;i<cnum;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("---------CLUSTER-"+i+"-----");
         a=0;
            for(int j=0;j<num;j++)
            {
                 if(data_set[j][row]==i)
                 {a++;
                for(int k=0;k<row;k++)
                {

                    System.out.print(data_set[j][k]+"  ");
                }
                c++;
                System.out.println();
                }
                 //System.out.println(num);

            }
               System.out.println("CLUSTER INSTANCES="+a);


        }
        System.out.println("TOTAL INSTANCE"+c);
    }


    public static void check()
{

    checker=0;
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
         //System.out.println("hii");
        if(Double.compare(data_set[i][row],data_set[i][row+1]) != 0)

        {
            checker=1;
            //System.out.println("hii " + i  + " " + data_set[i][4]+ " "+data_set[i][4]);
            break;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
  readFile();
   //
  init();
while(checker!=0)
 //for(int i=0;i<5;i++) 
  {

  print();
 s();
 newcenter();
 check();

    }
print11();
}
}
```